# Coin flip: Double or Nothing

Tags: probability, gambling

I have an amount of chips to bet on a fair coin flipping and landing on heads. For each time in a row that it does land on heads, the amount of chips in the bet is doubled by the house, and I am able to take away any portion of chips from the bet as they are won. Say I have one thousand chips. What should I bet, and when and how many chips should I take out from the bet when I do win?

Comment: is this problem similar to you're question?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox

Comment: It seems similar, but in this case the player seems to be able to take coins out of the pot between each coin flip. Also to determine the initial bet.

Comment: Oh so you don't have to put alway winnings back into bet, can just put portion?

Comment: I think that you can't win money on any strategy in a long run